# How to transpose and rotate frames and get new coordinates

Tags: transforms, ros-kinetic, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am new in the ROS world and still don't get some concepts.
Could anyone explain me how to use the transformPose?

Let's assume I have a global frame A and an end-of-efector frame B. Let's assume that in the frame B I have a point P_b.
I want to get P_b's coordinates in the frame A (P_b->a).
Mathematically speaking, it's really simple. But what are those steps in ROS?
I know I can get a translation vector and quaternions using lookupTransform applied to my frames. What comes next?
Do I have to calculate P_b->a manually or can call a function to get the new coordinates (transformPose or transformQuaterions?

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335584/how-to-transpose-and-rotate-frames-and-get-new-coordinates/) by [RobotsAreCool](https://answers.ros.org/users/47333/robotsarecool/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Presumably, you are using C++. If that is the case, you'd likely want to look to the `doTransform` methods of tf2. For example, there is an [overload of doTransform](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/tf2_geometry_msgs/html/c++/namespacetf2.html#abe5bbc43e831686558fcc1b8f1bc80cb) specifically for `geometry_msgs/Point` types. So if you had your point expressed in the B frame `P_b`, you could lookup the transform from A to B, and then apply that to B to get the point in the A frame.

**EDIT**

Adding a small Python example that assumes the `tf` tree already has a `frame_a` and a `frame_b` available.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import tf
import tf2_ros
import tf2_geometry_msgs

rospy.init_node("demo_lookup")

tfbuffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(tfbuffer)

tf1_listener = tf.TransformListener()

# give listeners time to receive required transforms
rospy.sleep(1.0)

# make Pose in the 'b' frame
p_b = tf2_geometry_msgs.tf2_geometry_msgs.PoseStamped()
p_b.header.frame_id = 'frame_b'
p_b.pose.position.y = 0.5
p_b.pose.orientation.w = 1.0

# Use tf2 to transform pose to the 'a' frame and print results. Best practice
# would wrap this in a try-except:
t_a_b = tfbuffer.lookup_transform('frame_a', 'frame_b', rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(1.0))
p_a = tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_pose(p_b, t_a_b)
rospy.loginfo("Pose expressed in 'frame_a' using tf2: \n%s\n", str(p_a))

# Use tf to transform pose to the 'a' frame and print results. Best practice
# would wrap this in a try-except:
p_a_tf1 = tf1_listener.transformPose('frame_a', p_b)
rospy.loginfo("Pose expressed in 'frame_a' using tf: \n%s\n", str(p_a_tf1))
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2019-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobotsAreCool](https://answers.ros.org/users/47333/robotsarecool/) on 2019-10-21**:
Hi @jarvischultz and thank you for you comment. I have to use python.
I think that transformPose does exactly what I need and I don't even need to call lookupTransform. However I cannot find any confirmation, which makes me unsure.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-10-21**:
`transformPose` should do exactly what you want. I will point out that that uses the old `tf` API instead of the newer `tf2` API. While the old API doesn't seem to be going away any time soon, I generally prefer using the new API.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-10-21**:
Sorry.. I didn't read your comment closely enough. I still thought you were in C++. I'll add a little code snippet to my answer illustrating how to do this in both APIs in Python.